# Show that if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $a\mid b$, then $a\leq b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, solution-verification

I know that the direct proof is pretty straightforward but I wanted to try proving by the contrapositive. So I would like a proof-verification but also I would like some feedback on the proof-writing because sometimes I feel like I might be a bit to long-winded. Thanks in advance!

Proceeding by the contrapositive we suppose $a>b$ and show that $a\nmid b$. Dividing through the inequality by $a$ (okay since $a\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$) we get that $\dfrac{b}{a}<1$. In particular we have that $0<\dfrac{b}{a}<1$ since both $a$ and $b$ are positive integers. This implies that $a\nmid b$, which we wanted to show.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: You should justify the last step. *Why* does $0<b/a<1$ imply that a does not divide b?

Comment: Since $0<\dfrac{b}{a}<1$ means $\dfrac{b}{a}\notin \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Of course you have to rule out $0$, since $17\;|\;0$.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for comments on your proof, so I hope the following is of interest.

While the proof is valid (assuming knowledge about rational numbers) I don’t feel this kind of argument to be compelling, as it uses much more machinery than needed (why can you divide through $a$ if $a$ doesn’t divide $b$? Why can you divide inequalities? why is positive/positive again positive? etc. etc.). The far more immediate contrapositive is (using $an\geq a \forall n\in \Bbb N$) that if $a>b$ any multiple $an > b$, so $a\not\mid b$... This argument uses nothing more than monotonicity of multiplication in $\Bbb N$!

Comment: Very informative! The part about not using to much machinery than needed seems like a good thing to always keep in mind when writing a proof. Your proof by contraposition was much more elegant.

Comment: Thank you very much :)